# On Friday morning, at night....but what about on\at Friday 9 AM?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, idiomatic-language

Should it be **on** Friday 9 AM or **at** Friday 9 AM?

Comment: I would not say either, but _on Friday at 9am_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[English club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm) describes the following rules for using prepositions for time:

> **at** PRECISE TIME (e.g. at 3 o'clock, at night)
>
> **in** MONTHS, YEARS, CENTURIES and LONG PERIOD (e.g. in May)
>
> **on** DAYS and DATES  (e.g.on Sunday)

Also,
When we say last, next, every, this we do not also use at, in, on.

e.g. I went to London last June. (not in last June)

So, the precise answer would be "on Friday at 9am"